# how to set iframe height to 100% with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, height

how to set iframe height to 100% with javascript
Example : http://mkb.ma/5f

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS for the iframe [that page](http://mkb.ma/5f):

```
#mkbnavbar iframe#srcpage {
  height:90%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:10;
}
```

And remaining 10% is given to bar at the top.

Answer (score 1):

He is actually using CSS to do this on this page:

```
#mkbnavbar iframe#srcpage {
height: 90%;
width:100%;
z-index: 10;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

}
```